# isomorphism between two division rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, division-ring

I have a (D,F)-bimodule $A$ where $D,F$ are division rings and $A = aF$ for some $a\in A$.

then for every $d\in D$, $da\in A$ so there exists a unique $f_d\in F$ such that $da = af_d$. Then I define the map $\phi:D\to F:d\mapsto f_d$. How do we show that this is an isomorphism? In particular, How do we show surjectivity?

Comment: Why should it be surjective? E.g., take $D = \Bbb{R}$, $A = F = \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Hum... Indeed that doesn't seem to work. In the text I'm reading, it is decently written the such a $\phi$ is an isomorphism...

Comment: @RobArthan How is $\mathbb{C}=a\mathbb{R}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Ah nevermind I've clearly misread your post

Comment: @tomak: what is the text you are reading?

Comment: Jacobson: structure of rings

Comment: I don't have the book to hand. What exactly does Jacobson say about this?

Comment: he exactly says what I have written

Comment: It seems to me after reflexion that when he says "isomorphism" it could potentially mean just an injective morphism. For example, elsewhere, he has a division ring extension $D/F$. He will then talk of a ring isomorphism of $F$ into $D$ but that makes no sense unless he means a isomorphism of $F$ unto it's image which is included in $D$.