# Complete centraliser in the ring of endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

My question is simple but I couldn't find a definition online.

What is a complete centraliser in the ring of endomorphisms?

Comment: Could you provide the sentence you saw it in with context?

Comment: It seems to me after reflexion that when he says "isomorphism" it could potentially mean just an injective morphism. For example, elsewhere, he has a division ring extension $D/F$. He will then talk of a ring isomorphism of $F$ into $D$ but that makes no sense unless he means a isomorphism of $F$ unto it's image which is included in $D$.

Comment: I think you meant to comment on [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796754/isomorphism-between-two-division-rings).

Comment: thanks you my mistake